# Compare 2 time datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server which has 2 columns `StartTime` AND `EndTime`. The datatype of both columns in `time(7)`. So when I view data in the table it can look like this:

> 08:33:00.0000000

or

> 19:33:00.0000000

I want to return all the rows in the table where StartTime and EndTime conflicts with another row.

Example table **TimeTable**

```
RowID  StartTime           EndTime
1      08:33:00.0000000    19:33:00.0000000
2      10:34:00.0000000    15:32:00.0000000
3      03:00:00.0000000    05:00:00.0000000
```

Type of query I am trying to do:

```
SELECT * FROM TimeTable 
WHERE RowID = 1 
AND 
TimeTable.StartTime AND EndTime 
Falls in range
(SELECT * FROM TimeTable WHERE RowID <> 1)
```

Expected result:

```
2      10:34:00.0000000    15:32:00.0000000
```

Comment: Your expected result is misleading.  If two rows overlap, don't you want *both* rows?  After all, each overlaps with the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logic like this for at least a fraction of a second of overlap:

```
select tt.*
from timetable tt
where exists (select 1
              from tt2
              where tt2.rowid <> tt.rowid and
                    tt2.endtime > tt.starttime and
                    tt2.starttime < tt.endtime
             );
```

Comment: Looks like OP only wants one row so `tt2.rowid < tt.rowid`